# Jquery Autocomplete displays results for the first time but for the next time page has to be refreshed?

Tags: jquery

```
//This is my jquery code

   $(function() { 
    var base_url = '/xxx';
        var autoCompleteURL = base_url + '/xxx/xxx';

        $("#village").autocomplete({
            source : autoCompleteURL,
            select : function(event, ui) {
                $("#village").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#village_id").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            autoFocus : true,
            change : function(event, ui) {
                addDistrict(ui.item.value);
            },
            focus : function(event, ui) {
                $("#village").val(ui.item.label);
            },
            cacheLength : 0
        });
    })
```

//Works fine for the first time but for the second time I will have to refresh the page .Any idea what could be done to handle this.After selecting the autocomplete value I am performing a search functionality which is an ajax call.

Comment: there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code, see this example. https://jsfiddle.net/6vdjxfyv/  I replaced your remote source with a static list. So perhpas the issue is with the server returning the results.

Comment: @SeanOB Yeah but is there any way to resolve that issue.

Comment: I suspect the issue is going to be with your addDistrict() method. Can you comment it out and see if the autocomplete works as expected?

Comment: @SeanOB No it does not work ...actually the same autocomplete works fine on another page since the page gets refereshed on Save or reset.But in another page search form is there and that does not get refreshed on click of search .Hence it does not show values for second search.

Comment: @SeanOB Only way to make the search form refresh on each search click.